# (Done) Reopen question on Computer Engineering/Science jobs

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

The question [Are there any Computer Engineering/Science jobs that don't require programming ALL day](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/114060/73791) is currently closed as *Too Broad*.

However, this question is really important, specially for fresh CS/IT graduates, as it touches fundamental concepts and aspects on what a Programming job consists of (and the false premise that coding is just typing).

I think that this is a valuable post for current and future users, and hereby **request you to consider reopening**.

Comment: Re-open vote cast.  Edit made it answerable IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has now been reopened.

Answer (score 1):

It might be important and useful, but that doesn't mean it's on topic (and there are plenty of other places on the internet that would be more than happy to take it).

It's essentially asking for a list of possible jobs.

If not that, it's asking for a list of other things you can be doing *in* a (Computer Science or other) job.

Creating list questions ["is simply not what we do here"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98334/list-questions-community-wiki).

Or it's asking for career advice (i.e. it can be rephrased to roughly "what job can I take so I won't be programming all day?").

Not to mention that this might not even be a general workplace question - a Computer Scientist may be able to answer the question, but I'm sceptical that someone in HR would be able to, which puts it outside the scope of this site as far as I'm concerned.